# Injecting precompiled handlebars template in Handlebars.template method

Tags: handlebars.js

Hi I am currently using Express Handlebars setup [https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars][1] to render compiled and pre-compiled templates. In case of pre-compilation I have configured express middleware to get handlebars templates as precompiled and manually configured registration of handlebars pre-compiled templates like this:

```
hbs.getTemplates('views/partials/page/', {
                    cache      : app.enabled('view cache'),
                    precompiled: true
                }).then(function (templates) {

           var templatesArr = hbs.handlebars.templates = hbs.handlebars.templates || {}

         // extract all templates names and values
        templates = Object.keys(hbs.handlebars.templates).map(function (name) {

                  //get precompiled template data
                  var templateSpec = templates[name]

                 //Inject precompiled data into Handlebars.template method
                 var precompileTemplateRef = hbs.handlebars.template(templateSpec)

                //templateSpec is treated as String rather than Object 
                //and this is where the things break because 
                //handlebars.template expects Object

                //Register precompileTemplateRef with Handlebars so that 
                //precompiled template can be extracted for later use by using 
                //template name

                templatesArr[name] = precompileTemplateRef

 });
```

When I run the express server, hbs.handlebars.template doesn't get executed because templateSpec mentioned above is received as a string rather than object.

Even using JSON.parse(templateSpec) doesn't work because precompiled output is not JSON BUT an Object literal.

Precompiled output looks something like this:

```
{"1":function(container,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {var helper;ret.......
```

I want to know if its possible to inject just the pre-compiled output at run time into Handlebars.template(templateSpec) OR Do I have to create precompiled template in file system which has registration with Handlebars.templates.

In case of compiled templates there are no issues.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue with Handlebars as per the following links:
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/922
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1033

```
var templateSpec = (new Function('return ' + templates[name])());
```

Will resolve the problem